# xtragrid copy selected rows to another xtragrid

Tags: c#, xtragrid

my environement: vs2012, C#

```
    public static IList GetList()
    {
        using (var ctx = new ProductCatalogEntities(Constants.EfConnectionString))
        {
            return (from c in ctx.Products
                    select new 
                        {
                            ProductId = c.ProductId
                            ,
                            Name = c.Name
                            ,
                            Code = c.Code
                            ,
                            Price = c.Price
                        }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

This method fills my first xtragrid, when I select some rows, I want to click a button to fill my second xtragrid with those selected rows, how to achieve this please?